# Heroku: Deploy frontend to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, frontend, backend

I need to deploy my frontend files to Heroku and some how merge it with Backend. I've been having my frontend and backend files separated building the project.
My backend is currently deployed to Heroku. https://git.heroku.com/hamsterwarz3000.git

How can I deploy my Frontend repository so that it can go live Heroku?
I been trying to push (git push Heroku ) but I 'm getting this error message:

> Blockquote  [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hamsterwarz3000.git'
> hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
> hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
> hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
> hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
> hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for detail

[Repository Backend](https://github.com/michelkabwe/hamsterwarz)

My frontend files also have it's own repository.
[Repository Frontend](https://github.com/michelkabwe/hamsterwarzfrontend)

Comment: it seems to me that your backend is more like a server for api, here's a link for hosting your react app https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-deploy-your-react-app-to-heroku-aedc28b218ae

Comment: The log output you shared is the _least_ helpful part of it. Please [edit] your question and show us what happens above this.